# What is the point of PUT when PATCH can effectively do the same thing

Tags: rest

From my understanding, if completely following the HTTP spec, if you are doing a PUT command you need to pass in all the data for the resource (whether or not it changes) and when doing a PATCH command you need to only pass in the data that is changing.  So if I had a resource in which I was going to change every value of it, the PUT and PATCH command would have the same request except for the HTTP verb being used.

From a backend prospective, I am finding it hard to come up with a viable reason to have different functionality for PUT and PATCH.  The REST API I have been building right now supports both methods however they point to the same code and the code really just does a PATCH as it does not request all the data of the resource, just the changed data.  I would like to have a really good reason to have to maintain a separate code path for PUT for all my resources as that adds a bit to code maintenance.

Is there any reason to really have different functionality for both PUT and PATCH when the code for PATCH can really do a PUT too (besides you should follow the spec as I don't find that a great reason on its own in this case)?

Is it considered bad practice or acceptable to have both PUT and PATCH accept only a list of changed data of the resource?

Answer (score 3):

Even though both verbs seem quite similar, there are small, mostly semantic differences that should be considered when using one of the verbs.

- PUT is idempotent, PATCH is not, which means that the side effects of a sequence of identical PUT-requests are the same as for a single request. This is not true for PATCH, even though it *can* be *forced* to be idempotent.
- It is possible to use PATCH in a way where you need to know the server-side state of the resource first. This makes collisions more 'dangerous' than PUT-requests, because if you base the operation on a point/state that has already changed in the meantime, you might corrupt the resource. It's on the client's behalf to take care such cases. This is not necessary for simple operations like appending a list item (because the previous state doesn't matter).
- Unlike PUT, a PATCH is not of the same entity as the resource it modifies. It only describes some sort of delta, but not a full representation of the resource. Therefore, it is not quite true when you say "...if I had a resource in which I was going to change every value of it, the PUT and PATCH command would have the same request except for the HTTP verb being used". This also means, that a PATCH must not necessarily be of a smaller document size than the whole resource data you would use with PUT.
- > "It is expected that different patch document formats will be

> appropriate for different types of resources and that no single format
> will be appropriate for all types of resources.  Therefore, there is
> no single default patch document format that implementations are
> required to support.  Servers MUST ensure that a received patch
> document is appropriate for the type of [the requested] resource"
> - [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

- The comparison between PUT an PATCH is not quite trivial as it may seem, because you also should consider POST, since POST can also be used for partial modification.
- Right now, PATCH is just a proposal and has not been completely/officially standardized yet.

So, as you can see, there are some differences between PUT and PATCH. Sometimes it can be important to be able to accurately describe the changes of a resource, so there sure are appropriate use-cases for PATCH. I think it's a good idea to provide both, but be aware that they're not really the same. Use PATCH for realative/partial updates and PUT to update the entire resource.

Comment: Thanks for some more insight into this issue.  It almost seems like I should just support PATCH and not PUT because I can't think of a single use case in which I would need to completely replace a resource where just updating the resource would not work.

Comment: @ryanzec I'm glad it helped a little :) But maybe you still should provide a PUT method because that's what I (and probably most of the users) would expect in order to modify a resource. Also, as mentioned above, PATCH is rather new and might not be supported by every tool/frameworks that implements HTTP and your clients might want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between PUT and PATCH is that PUT asks the server to completely ignore the current state, while PATCH asks the server to consider the current state before applying the payload.

You think there are no differences because you're using PATCH to update with a partial representation, passing the data that is changing. That's not how it works. PATCH should use a diff format that makes explicit the current state you're applying the change to, and the resulting state.

For instance, in a JSON API you want to update the `email` parameter with a patch. The current email is myemail@example.com. You shouldn't just send:

```
{'email': 'mynewemail@example.com'}
```

You MUST send something like:

```
{'old_email': 'myemail@example.com', 'new_email': 'mynewemail@example.com'}
```

The format may be designed by your, or you may adopt an standardized diff format, depending on your needs. There's an RFC proposal for a standard [JSON patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) format to be used in these cases.

The use case for a PUT is when you need to completely replace something, ignoring completely whatever is in there, if anything. For instance, an user who is updating his profile. No matter what he does, you want to keep the latest version, ignoring whatever existed before.

The use case for a PATCH is when you need to update something, while considering the current state, and only if it still matches the state it had the last time you checked. For instance, you need to flag some user for being behind in his payments, but between the start of the job and the actual request, the user actually paid and his profile was already updated by another client of your API. If you flag his account as unpaid by sending a full representation with a PUT, you'll overwrite the data saying he has already paid. If you update with a PATCH, the request will be applied only if the user still has the unpaid state you've seen before.

To answer your last question, it's not acceptable to do partial updates with PUT. A PUT request is a complete replacement.