If PATCH can do everything that PUT can do then why even PUT exists?
If PATCH can do everything that PUT can do then why even PUT exists?
I researched a lot on this topic and I am able to know basic difference between the two.
PUT is for creating or updating/replacing the existing. we need to send whole body here
PATCH is for updating only some fields like here we only send fields which needs to be updated.
BUT if we send whole body in PATCH then it works exactly like PUT...So with help of PATCH we can update few itmes also and we can update the whole resource..then why PUT even exists?
Can only PATCH be used? NO PUT method required? or Am i missing soemthing?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/use-of-put-vs-patch-methods-in-rest-api-real-life-scenarios

Sorry to say but not able understand exact use of PUT? why we need PUt when we can do everyhting with PATCH

What is not explained about this in the linked question? Multiple people already explained the difference: "PUT ➔ Updates a resource entirely" | "PATCH ➔ Update an existing resource partially" - reference

If I send whole body in PATCH req it works exactly like PUT.
Then why do we have PUT? if PATCH can do PUT work also.
@DarkBee

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386606/what-is-the-point-of-put-when-patch-can-effectively-do-the-same-thing

then why PUT even exists? If I only need to update one small part of a resource, it's easier to do that with PATCH.  Recreating the entire resource with PUT is a lot more work, and might not even be possible (permissions) or desired (history).


If PATCH can do everything that PUT can do then why even PUT exists?

POST can do everything that PUT, PATCH, GET, HEAD, DELETE.... can do; why do these other methods exist?

And the answer is something like this: when we constrain message semantics (meaning), introduce the ability to make general purpose components more powerful, because they can act on the properties introduced by the additional constraints.
For your specific question: PUT means PUT - that is to say, it communicates that we are intending that the current representation of the target resource be replaced with the representation enclosed in the request content.
And that meaning is fundamentally idempotent; general purpose components (ex: the browser) can take advantage of this by, for example, repeating requests if a response is lost.
In contrast, the semantics of PATCH are not idempotent - there's no reason to expect that applying the same patch document twice produces the same result as applying the patch document once.

Also, historically, PUT exists first; it appears in appendix D of RFC 1945 (May 1996) and becomes part of the core set of HTTP 1.1 in RFC 2068 (Jan 1997).
HTTP PATCH is standardized by RFC 5789 (March, 2010).
Keep in mind that the HTTP-wg works hard to ensure that HTTP is backwards compatible; even if PATCH were to make PUT completely irrelevant (which it doesn't, see above), we'd probably continue to include it in the standard just to avoid breaking everything that currently uses it.
We'll probably see the same choice when GET-with-a-body is standardized; GET isn't likely to be deprecated.

Great answer, just to add to that: it is surely impossible to implement full idempotence semantics in PATCH, but you at least can nail down the state that you delta-update with ETags. Applying the same PATCH request to the same ETag-bound state (If-Match) should give you the same result...
